# Get the latest value from array

Tags: javascript

In my application, i am in the need to get the latest value among any number of values and to get the latest, date is the key factor.

```js
const data = [
'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2018-01-01]',
'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]',
'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2017-05-01]',
'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2018-01-01]',
'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2017-05-01]',
'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2019-05-01]'
]

console.log(data);
```

How to get the result from the array as `PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]` and `PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2019-05-01]` which is the latest data comparing with others?

I need to get two values for now.. But my real application has more than 100's of different names (duplicated) with date (different).

I have multiple users like this and repeated multiple times but the date will be different, how can i filter the results with the name has latest date?

Comment: Did you attempt anything?

Comment: try Array.from(data ).pop()

Comment: @epascarello, Tried getting the date out of string but i am on the wrong way and hence not posted those.. In order to keep the things simpler i just seeked help with the things i have.

Comment: So you need to build a regular expression to match the pattern or use sub strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a quick sorting and than looping over it to find the first occurrence of the key.

```js
const data = [
'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2018-01-01]',
'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]',
'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2017-05-01]',
'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2018-01-01]',
'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2017-05-01]',
'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2019-05-01]'
]

//match the parts to get the role and date
var re = /(.*)\s\[valid from (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\]/
var latest = 
  data
    .sort()  // sort it so they are in order
    .reverse()  // reverse it so the latest date is first
    .reduce((obj, item) => { // find the first keys
      const [match, key, date] = item.match(re)  // get the parts from reg exp match
      if (!obj[key]) obj[key] = date;  // if we do not have the key let store it
      return obj; // return the object for reduce
    }, {})


console.log(latest)
```

If you do not want to sort, than you can compare the date strings

```js
const data = [
'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2018-01-01]',
'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]',
'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2017-05-01]',
'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2018-01-01]',
'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2017-05-01]',
'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2019-05-01]'
]

//match the parts to get the role and date
var re = /(.*)\s\[valid from (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\]/
var latest = 
  data
    .reduce((obj, item) => { // find the first keys
      const [match, key, date] = item.match(re)  // get the parts from reg exp match
      if (!obj[key] || obj[key] < date) obj[key] = date;  // if we do not have the key let store it or if new date is grater
      return obj; // return the object for reduce
    }, {})


console.log(latest)
```

Comment: Just `.push().` them to an array and then sort.

Comment: This solution works but is very dependent on the format of the original strings, since it uses alphanumeric `sort` on the strings before extracting the "parts". For example an extra space or case inconsistency would throw off the result. Seems that the real problem is that data in the OP's question is in the wrong format.

Comment: @AaronBeall I love when people put in different requirements on the OPs question. This answer fits the data provided. If there are differences in it, then the OP would need to disclose this. Sorting based on strings with that data format will produce the same results regardless of the situation. So yes if the data could differ, then a few clean up steps would be needed. In this test case provided it does not make any difference.

Comment: @epascarello Yes, it works, but it's fragile. That's an important thing to keep in mind, IMO. Put another way: I wouldn't pass this in a code review. But it's hard to say what the "right" solution is without more context.

Answer (score 1):

1. you have to parse the date from the string (e.g. `dataRow.split('valid from ')[1].split(']')[0]` or use regex)
2. sort by the date
3. take the first value

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are always formatted like this, then use substring to get 10 characters starting at -11 position, that would give you the date. After that you have to compare each date and select the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
    'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2018-01-01]',
    'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]',
    'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2017-05-01]',
    'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2018-01-01]',
    'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2017-05-01]',
    'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2019-05-01]'
    ]

//REGEX THAT MATCH DATE FROM STRING
const dateRegex = /([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))/;

reorderedIndexes = [];

//From data we extract dates and their indexes and store it to another array;
data.forEach((dataValue, index)=>{
    let dataValueDate = dataValue.match(dateRegex)[0];
    reorderedIndexes.push({index: index, date: dataValueDate});
});

//Then we sort temporary array by dates and map it so it will contain reordered indexes only
reorderedIndexes = reorderedIndexes.sort((a,b)=>{
    return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
}).map((d)=>{
    return d.index;
});

//At the end we use reorderedIndexes and based on them map the appropriate value from data array.
data = reorderedIndexes.map((reorderedIndex)=> data[reorderedIndex]);

console.log(data);

/*
RESULT
[ 'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2019-05-01]',
  'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2019-01-01]',
  'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2018-01-01]',
  'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2018-01-01]',
  'PROF.. / Professional [valid from 2017-05-01]',
  'PRIN.. / Principal [valid from 2017-05-01]' ]
*/
```